# MS Access VBA to replace symbols in XML documents

Tags: xml, vba, replace

I have been trying to use the code below, it is an edited version of one above that allows me to pick multiple files. The problem is this... 1. The first file replaces and saves perfectly 2. The second file replaces while also adding the contents of the first file 3. The Third file replaces while also adding the contents of the first 2 file 4. And so on...

any suggestions?

```
Private Sub Command483_Click()
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("DeleteDetailsTable")
qdf.Execute


Dim StrFileName As String
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant


Dim sBuf As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim sFileName As String

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
    .InitialFileName = "c:\saample\*.xml"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems

           sFileName = vrtSelectedItem
           iFileNum = FreeFile()
           Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum
           Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
                Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
                sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
           Loop
           Close iFileNum
           sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "&", "and")
           iFileNum = FreeFile
           Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
           Print #iFileNum, sTemp

           Close #iFileNum



     DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        Next vrtSelectedItem
    Else
    End If
End With
Set fd = Nothing
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
       Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
            Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
            sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
       Loop
```

Each pass through the `For Each vrtSelectedItem` loop simply keeps adding content into `sTemp` (which is why each time you write it contains the content of all of the files before).

You can fix it by simply clearing (resetting) `sTemp` at the start of each iteration:

```
For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
   sFileName = vrtSelectedItem
   iFileNum = FreeFile()

   ' Add the next line
   sTemp = ""
   Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum
   Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
      Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
      sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
   Loop
```

Comment: I just tested it and it worked perfectly. Thank you.